# Display string data from Python script using HTML

Tags: python

Is there any way that shows data from python script using HTML?

For example, I want to generate random numbers for each seconds at WebSocketClient.py and trasmit them to Web server. On WebServer.html, random numbers are displayed for every seconds.

PC (Server)
- WebServer.html (port is specified)

Python(Raspi, Client)
- WebSocketClient.py (Input:IP of PC and port)

I searched several methods, but they are not suitable for me. I guess 'WebSocket' is the best way to do this, however most of examples are .html(client) and .py(server).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to evaluate an HTML input (from a web server) using a python script on your client.

This would involve two steps: Retrieving the input data from the web server and parsing it.

Take a look at the topics of [web scraping](https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/) and [html parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).

[Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a widely used library for this purpose.